# VS Code после компиляции плагином Language Support for Java классы создаются в другой папке а не в проекте рядом

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Помогите разобраться.

VS Code после компиляции плагином Language Support for Java классы создаются в другой папке а не в проекте рядом. Не могу понять почему плагин создает классы не в проекте рядом в папку bin как во всех нормальных IDE а делает вывод по пути C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\f68c89f042ba12ec138073f14c5ea7ec\redhat.java\jdt_ws\java_dcfb5174\bin.

Уже неделю бьюсь не могу понять как убрать эти каракули с вывода в терминале и заменить этот путь на свой проект. Чтобы классы выводило в папку моего проекта а не по этому пути \f68c89f042ba12ec138073f14c5ea7ec\redhat.java\jdt_ws\java_dcfb5174\bin.

Скрин каракуль в терминале прилагаю. Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить эту папку на свой проект, чтобы классы лежали в проекте а не у черта на куличках в папках с каракулями. Заранее благодарен всем кто поможет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите [maven](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build). Вот он при компиляции создаст нужные вам файлы. Maven сам тоже установите чтоб mvn работал с терминала.

По поводу файлов указанных вами это сама среда создаёт для работы на лету, не забывайте VS Code текстовый редактор. Если использовать команды javac и прочие то можно убедиться что файлы создаются как надо

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, попробую maven